# How to insert data into existing pdf template text filed with bold and also it is editable using itext?

Tags: pdf, itext

This is my code

```
String soruce="E:\\PT\\iText\\TextBox.pdf";
String destination="E:\\PT\\iText\\TextBoxOP.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(soruce);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(destination));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
form.setField("Text1", "Bruno Lowagie");
```

I need **Bruno** Lowagie Like this in pdf text field

Comment: try `form.setField("Text1", "<strong>Bruno</strong> Lowagie");`

Comment: I tried but it will display same <strong>Bruno</strong> Lowagie in pdf my pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Below is the action file with the help of which I was able to get What I needed..

https://pranavom.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/modify-pdf-using-fpdffpdi-library/

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is it support Java?

Comment: I am using iText pdf library